# Executing method outside onCreat() - work without entering the activity

Tags: android

I have programmed the TimeTable app to help me know the lectures and alert me when the time of the lecture comes, the problem is that the function of get the next lucture(getNextLecture();) does not work unless I open the activity because the function exists in the OnCreat() method of the activity.
This is my Code (not the full code!):

Main activity (AlarmMe):

```
public class AlarmMe extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(AlarmMe.class.getName(), "AlarmMe opened!");
    timetableDao = new TimetableDao(this);
    **getNextLecture();**

    Log.i(TAG, "AlarmMe.onCreate()");

    mAlarmList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_list);

    mAlarmListAdapter = new AlarmListAdapter(this);
    mAlarmList.setAdapter(mAlarmListAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(mAlarmList);


    mAlarm = new Alarm(this);
    mAlarm.fromIntent(getIntent());

    mDateTime = new DateTime(this);

    mTitle="Time is up !!";
    mAlarm.setTitle(mTitle);
}



private void getNextLecture() {
    int day = MyTime.CURRENT_DAY();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_next_class);
    if (day != Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
        /* It's weekend! */
        tv.setText("No classes in the weekend!");
    } else {
    List<TimetableEntry> entries = timetableDao.getMyTimetableForDay(
                MyTime.CURRENT_SEMESTER(), day,
            MyTime.CURRENT_TIME());

    if (entries.size() == 0) {
        tv.setText("No more classes today!");
    } else {
        TimetableEntry nextClass = entries.get(0);

        String courseAndLocation = "<b>" + nextClass.getCourse().getName()
                + "</b>";
        courseAndLocation += "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Building: ";
        Building building = nextClass.getBuilding();
        if (building != null) {
            courseAndLocation += "<a href=\"" + building.getMap() + "\">";
            courseAndLocation += building.getDescription();
            courseAndLocation += "</a>";
        } else {
            courseAndLocation += nextClass.getBuildingName();
        }

        Room room = nextClass.getRoom();
        courseAndLocation += "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Room: ";
        if (room != null) {
            courseAndLocation += room.getDescription();
        } else {
            courseAndLocation += nextClass.getRoomName();
        }

        if (!"".equals(nextClass.getComment())) {
            courseAndLocation += "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                    + nextClass.getComment();
        }
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(courseAndLocation));
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        //هنا عدل

        MyTime timenow = nextClass.getStart();
        a=timenow.toString().split(":");
        mYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mHour = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
        mMinute =Integer.parseInt(a[1])-5;
        mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
        mAlarm.setDate(mCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mAlarmListAdapter.add(mAlarm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just study activity lifecycle and there is no question because you didn't ask any

Comment: Use a `Service` instead. Start it from your activity, then let it run in the background.